# Swift - Operator == Cannot be applied to two Int operands

Tags: ios, swift

This is freaking me out and is super-annoying. I've had similar issues before but don't know how I fixed it.

So, I have this condition

```
for jfa:Dictionary<String, AnyObject> in jfaDict {
    if Int(jfa[JobType.JobNoKey]) == jobNo
    {
        //Some stuff to do here
    }
}
```

JobType.JobNoKey is  a string while jobNo is an Int

And I'm getting the following error:

> Binary operator '==' cannot be applied to two Int operands

What does this mean?

Comment: It's a bad error message. If you want us to offer solutions you need to include more information, like the types of `jfa` and `.JobNoKey`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to unwrap `jfa[]` first:

```
if jfa[JobType.JobNoKey] as? Int == jobNo {
    //Some stuff to do here
}
```

Comment: In that case, jfa[JobType.JobNoKey] is an implicitly unwrapped optional, so remove the "!" from "as!".

Comment: Ok, so the above solution is actually working. I had another condition, chained with an "&&" after this one which was actually causing the issue. (giving the same wrong error). Thanks a lot for helping.

Answer (score 0):

Try to typecast as `Int` first before making the comparison

```
if let value = jfa[JobType.JobNoKey] as? Int {
  //value has an Int now
  if value == jobNo
  {
    //Some stuff to do here
  }
} else {
//casting as Int failed, AnyObject could not be converted to Int
//Some other stuff to do here
}
```